# .png extension not stored to database

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload images using php and html form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="products_photo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" class="prodid" name="id">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="photo" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Photo</label>

                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" name="upload"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Update</button>
          </form>
```

But the issue is png extensions are not being saved to database. jpg and jpeg are stored.[image: no png extension saved to database]
Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

I am using a function to make slug for images, but the extensions for jpg and jpeg are stored in database but not for png files.
the php file:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'];

    $conn = $pdo->open();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(['id'=>$id]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if(!empty($filename)){
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $new_filename = $row['slug'].'_'.time().'.'.$ext;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], '../images/'.$new_filename);   
    }
    
    try{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE products SET photo=:photo WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->execute(['photo'=>$new_filename, 'id'=>$id]);
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Product photo updated successfully';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    }

    $pdo->close();

}
else{
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Select product to update photo first';
}
```

?>

Comment: Post the `products_photo.php` code

Comment: @Musa yes, added.